# TYPO3 DDEV installation upload to server

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, ddev

I have a local ddev based TYPO3 site. If I want to upload it on my apache server there is some path issues with the resource files like JS,CSS and images.

This is the path for the css file on my local server...  this works perfect:
`typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Public/Dist/Css/main.css`

On my apache server following path gives a 404 error
`/typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Public/Dist/Css/main.css`

Is there a way to change the base path of the production environment?

Comment: Please take the [tour], and see [ask] and [help/on-topic]: We can't guess what "can't get it to work" means, and this is not a service-site, but one to answer specific _programming related_ questions. Yours doesn't look like being programming related, on top of being very unspecific. You may want to edit it to fit for this site, or find another place where it's on topic

Comment: @OlafKock ok i changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://usetypo3.com/composer-changes-for-typo3-v11-and-v12.html) describes your issue probably.

The main issue if you want to keep the old structure is to use

```
"typo3/cms-composer-installers": "^2.0 || ^3.0"
```

without version 4.
Else the whole structure is created differently.

Nevertheless you might be able to repair the current state by using paths like this:

```
EXT:sitepackage/...
```

as soon as you use `typo3conf/ext` directly it won't work.
Certainly you could create symlinks but that's likely not the best approach.